# How can I extract data from a command output with Bash?

Tags: bash, text-processing, output, google-drive

I'm new to Linux and I'd like to get the "DRIVE GB" from this output:

```
[randall@home gdrive]$ drive quota 
Name: Randall D
Account type:   UNLIMITED
Bytes Used: 290959662516         (270.98GB)
Bytes Free: 10995116277760       (10.00TB)
Bytes InTrash:  0                    (0.00B)
Total Bytes:    11286075940276       (10.26TB)

* Space used by Google Services *
Service                              Bytes                               
DRIVE                                270.98GB                            
PHOTOS                               0.00B                               
GMAIL                                0.00B                               
Space used by all Google Apps        270.98GB
```

I want to get the "270.38" from DRIVE                                270.98GB. I tried with sed reading a few posts here but couldn’t get it.

Comment: And what will you do when it goes up to `0.921TB`? It seems to me that the `GB` part is important here.

Answer (score 6):

```
drive quota | sed -n 's/^DRIVE[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([0-9.]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
```

Would extract the sequences of 1 or more decimal digits or `.` following a sequence of 1 or more blanks following `DRIVE` itself at the start of the line.

If your `sed` supports the `-E` option, it would be prettier with:

```
drive quota | sed -En 's/^DRIVE[[:blank:]]+([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'
```

Though then, you might as well use `perl`:

```
drive quota | perl -lne 'print $1 if /^DRIVE\h+([\d.]+)/'
```

With GNU `grep`, when built with (recent for `\K`) PCRE support:

```
drive quota | grep -Po '^DRIVE\h+\K[\d.]+'
```

With `awk`, you can also do:

```
drive quota | awk '$1 == "DRIVE" {print 0+$2}'
```